Custom notifications in Azure devops

How to create custom notification in Azure Devops based on squad future backlogs are falling below a threshold?
Say the refined stories are not available n the team backlog for the next 2 sprints.
I want to trigger email notifications to the respective team product owner and business analyst when above event occur on a daily basis.

How to create custom notification in Azure Devops when the squad velocity is below the plan sprint on sprint?
I want to trigger email notifications to the respective team scrum master and delivery lead when above event occur on daily basis



I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can set the email notification based on squad backlogs threshold and squad velocity.
Currently, Azure DevOps boards only supports setting notifications at the work item level. Refer to this doc: Team and project-level notifications
Work    
- a work item is created
- a work item is changed
- a work item is deleted
- a work item is restored
- a work item is moved from this team project

I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: Developer Community to report this feature.

Kevin, Thanks.  I have posted to Microsoft.  Is there a way using custom iteration using ado fields to arrive at backlog health and notify under configuration
